# Joomla intro image as read more link

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5

I want to make the joomla articles intro image to behave like the read more, and the title link. So the user clicks the image, and the article loads.

I'm not an PHP expert but maybe this is the readmore links code:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->item->readmore_link; ?>" class="button<?php echo $this->item->params->get('pageclass_sfx'); ?>">
        <?php if ($this->item->readmore_register) :
            echo JText::_('Register to read more...');
        elseif ($readmore = $this->item->params->get('readmore')) :
            echo $readmore;
        else :
                echo JText::_("Read Article");
        endif; ?></a>
```

This is what i want to do with every intro image on my joomla site.
Thanks !

Comment: What intro image? Are you putting an image in the content area above the read more line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just resolved it!

your way of thinking helped me. Thank you!

here's my code:

```
        <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($this->item->slug, $this->item->catid)); ?>">

    <?php
        $images = json_decode($item->images);
        if (isset($images->image_intro) and !empty($images->image_intro)) {
            $imgfloat = (empty($images->float_intro)) ? $params->get('float_intro') : $images->float_intro;
            $class = (htmlspecialchars($imgfloat) != 'none') ? ' class="size-auto align-'.htmlspecialchars($imgfloat).'"' : ' class="size-auto"';
            $title = ($images->image_intro_caption) ? ' title="'.htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro_caption).'"' : '';
            echo '<img'.$class.$title.' src="'.htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro).'" alt="'.htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro_alt).'" />';
        }

        echo $this->item->introtext;

    ?>

    </a>
```

Answer (score 2):

for Joomla 2.5:

in your override for _item.php (Location: yourtemplate\html\mod_articles_news\item.php)
place the following line:

```
<?php if ($params->get('image')) : ?>
    <?php  $images = json_decode($item->images); ?>
    <?php  if (isset($images->image_intro) and !empty($images->image_intro)) : ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $item->link;?>"><img src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro); ?>" alt="<?php echo   htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro_alt); ?>"/></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Place it there where you would like it to show up 
For example after:

```
<?php echo $item->beforeDisplayContent; ?>
```

Your intro image has become a link now.
the isset part, makes sure that if a viewer uses Internet Explorer, it doesn't show up a small red cross box.

Just for the information:
in blog_item.php you can find an example code how it's shown up in an article. Here you can also find the code for imagefloat etc.

```
<?php  if (isset($images->image_intro) and !empty($images->image_intro)) : ?>
<?php $imgfloat = (empty($images->float_intro)) ? $params->get('float_intro') : $images->float_intro; ?>
<div class="img-intro-<?php echo htmlspecialchars($imgfloat); ?>">
<img
    <?php if ($images->image_intro_caption):
        echo 'class="caption"'.' title="' .htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro_caption) .'"';
    endif; ?>
    src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro); ?>" alt="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro_alt); ?>"/>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

So let me start by explaining what the code that you've posted above does. The entire block of code generates one link: there are a bunch of if statements that are determined based off some settings. For example, if you have set that people need to register in order to read more, the link will say "Register to read more..."

The part that we're interested in here, however, since we want to turn images into links, is the URL that we want the images to link to. This is right in the first line:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->item->readmore_link; ?>"
```

so we know that the URL is provided dynamically thanks to `$item->item->readmore_link` and all this code is doing is echoing it into the HTML.

All that's left is to edit your Joomla template of the page on which you have your images (probably the same file you took this code from). It looks like this should be part of a greater PHP loop, which loops through all the posts. Somewhere above where you found this code, should be code for the intro image that goes along with that post.

I'm not sure what it'll look like, it could be a `<img src="<? stuff here; ?> />` or it could be dynamically generated. Keep reading. If you're still not sure where to find it at the end, edit your post with the full code of the template where you got the above snipping from. Regardless of what it looks like, it is referred to as `<WHATEVER IMAGE CODE YOU FOUND ABOVE>` in the following step:

You have to wrap that image with "a" tags so that it looks like the following:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->item->readmore_link; ?>"> <WHATEVER IMAGE CODE YOU FOUND ABOVE> </a>
```

That should do it. Let me know if you have any trouble, I'll be more than happy to make my post more specific if you can provide more detailed information, but I've tried to explain it well enough that you should be able to figure it out with a couple tries.

Comment: Your idea is good, but there is no intro image code in a standard Joomla article. We'll need more info to know where he's getting the image from.

Comment: I don't have a Joomla background, only a PHP one, but I figured that maybe he's using a template or theme or something that allows him to upload an image. It'll either be generated through a helper or manually with a dynamic URL. I'm guessing most likely it'll be something like a `<img src=<?php echo $this_articles_image_link; ?> />` but either way my solution should work for him. You're right in that the only thing that makes this question difficult is his lack of providing details.

Comment: I figured by your answer. If he's using an extension to allow for article images then there will be image specific code. If he's just putting an image in the article summary, then it's going to take some regex magic to make it work.

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about Joomla has had a standard intro image since 2.5.

Answer (score 1):

As you stated you are not a PHP expert, it sounds like your best bet will be to use a Joomla extension that has similar functionality to what you want.

I believe [mod_minifrontpage](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/frontend-news/2751) will work for what you need. It allows you to display a list of articles, and it generates thumbnails for those articles based on the first image to be referenced.

Answer (score 1):

There are article intro images in J, since 1.7.5 and now in latest 2.5.3
what you need is change the defaults for component_content,

you can do it 2 ways, editing views in yourinstall/components/com_content/views/

or use template overrides , you first need to know if your template IS using overrides otherwise if you edit component views in the component itself  you will not see changes.

to verify this , go to 
site_name/templates/template_name/html  folder and check if there is folder name 
com_content ,

if that is the case than your template is using overrides and any edits should be done trough there not through component

now to the actual code

this is in 
components\com_content\views\featured\tmpl\default_item.php  ( THIS I DEFAULT FRONTPAGE ARTICLE VIEW)

```
<?php  if (isset($images->image_intro) and !empty($images->image_intro)) : ?>
    <?php $imgfloat = (empty($images->float_intro)) ? $params->get('float_intro') : $images->float_intro; ?>

    <div class="img-intro-<?php echo htmlspecialchars($imgfloat); ?>">
    <img
        <?php if ($images->image_intro_caption):
            echo 'class="caption"'.' title="' .htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro_caption) .'"';
        endif; ?>
        src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro); ?>" alt="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro_alt); ?>"/>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

all you would need to do is wrap a element around IMG tag with readmore link like this

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->item->readmore_link; ?>">

<img
        <?php if ($images->image_intro_caption):
            echo 'class="caption"'.' title="' .htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro_caption) .'"';
        endif; ?>
        src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro); ?>" alt="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro_alt); ?>"/>



</a>
```

DO NOT forget that if there is template override for com_content you wold need to edit the featured/default_item.php inside it

Answer (score 1):

In Joomla 3.1, the intro_image layout has been moved to the layouts/joomla/content folder. In my situation, it is called from com_content/views/category/tmpl/blog_item.php like so:

```
<?php echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.content.intro_image', $this->item); ?>
```

I moved that file to my template/html/com_content/category/blog_item.php and then wrapped the call to JLayoutHelper like so:

```
<?php $link = JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($this->item->slug, $this->item->catid)); ?>
<a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">
<?php echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.content.intro_image', $this->item); ?>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Gantry installed on Joomla 3.1, the overrides are in a different location.  You will want to navigate to plugins/system/gantry/overrides/3.0/2.5/com_content/category/blog_item.php and wrap the intro image with the read more link code.

```
    <?php $link = JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($this->item->slug, $this->item->catid)); ?>
<a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><img
        <?php if ($images->image_intro_caption):
            echo 'class="caption"'.' title="' .htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro_caption) .'"';
        endif; ?>
        src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro); ?>" alt="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro_alt); ?>"/></a>
```