# Linking intro image in Joomla 3.3.1

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I would like to turn all intro images on the blog layout to links to the articles just as read more does.
Found this post here:
[Joomla 3.1 intro image as read more link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654706/joomla-3-1-intro-image-as-read-more-link)

The solution here is to replace the code in default_item.php from this:

```
<img
     <?php if ($images->image_intro_caption):
        echo 'class="caption"'.' title="' .htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro_caption) .'"';
     endif; ?>
     src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro); ?>" alt="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro_alt); ?>"/>
```

To this:

```
<a href="<?php echo JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($this->item->slug, $this->item->catid)); ?>"><img
     <?php if ($images->image_intro_caption):
        echo 'class="caption"'.' title="' .htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro_caption) .'"';
     endif; ?>
     src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro); ?>" alt="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro_alt); ?>"/> </a>
```

Followed the instructions, added an override folder in my template, copied default_item.php to it and made the change to the code. Nothing happened. I then tried to change the same lines in the component folder just to see if the problem was with the template override, nothing.

Is there another way of doing this?

Thanks in advance,

Guy.

Comment: What folder name did you use in the template?

Comment: I've used the following path: templates/mytemplate/html/com_content/featured

Comment: Joomla assumes that you will have you images in the image folder. You would only use the template folder for something that you want the template to use not individual articles. Also for templates if you want to store images put them in the template images folder, again then Joomla will know where to find them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

default_item.php is only used as part of the featured articles view.  If you are using the blog view, then the files appear under com_content/views/category/

The image itself is generated under com_content/views/category/blog_item.php on line 35

```
<?php echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.content.intro_image', $this->item); ?>
```

Change this to (via your template override)

```
<a href="<?php echo JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($this->item->slug, $this->item->catid)); ?>">
<?php echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.content.intro_image', $this->item); ?>
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you please tell me the folder override path so I can create it appropriately?

Comment: Hi Richard, found the path myself, thank you very much for your help, it works great.